# xgboost watchlist parameter: DMatrix object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, xgboost

I am trying to train a xgboost model on a dataset `X-train, X_test`. 
Code:

```
xgb_params = {
    "objective": "multi:softmax",
    "eta": 0.3,
    "num_class": 62,
    "max_depth": 10,
    "nthread": 4,
    "eval_metric": "merror",
    "print.every.n": 1
    #"silent": 1
}
num_rounds = 2

mask = np.random.choice([False, True], len(X_train), p=[0.75, 0.25])
not_mask = [not i for i in mask]

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train[not_mask], label=y[not_mask])
dtrain_watch = xgb.DMatrix(X_train[mask], label=y[mask])
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test)

gbdt = xgb.train(xgb_params, dtrain, num_rounds, dtrain_watch)
preds = gbdt.predict(dtest)
```

But I am getting error: `TypeError: 'DMatrix' object is not iterable` on the second last line.

What needs to be done?

EDIT:
If I typecast to `np.array` deliberately, I get `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

EDIT 2:
If I avoid `DMatrix` fully this way: `watchlist = list(np.append(X_train[mask], np.matrix(y[mask]).transpose(), axis=1))` I get another error

```
xgboost.py", line 340, in __init__
    raise TypeError('invalid cache item: {}'.format(type(d).__name__))
TypeError: invalid cache item: matrix
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `DMatrix` has iteration support: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L127

Comment: True, so what should I typecast it to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/python/python_intro.md), the monitoring datasets should be passed in the following form:

```
evallist  = [(dtest,'eval'), (dtrain,'train')]
```

So, your code should be changed to something like this:

```
evallist  = [(dtrain_watch, 'eval')]
gbdt = xgb.train(xgb_params, dtrain, num_rounds, evallist)
```

Also, you may want to use

```
not_mask = ~mask
```

instead so that the resulting mask is a Boolean numpy array instead of a list of bools. Otherwise, the slicing may not work as you expected although there's no error (check the dimension of the training and validation data in your original code).

Answer (score 1):

```
watchlist = [(dtest, 'test'), (dtrain, 'train')]
bst = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_rounds, watchlist)
```

This worked very fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but maybe this helps someone. 
In my case the order of eval and train set in the watchlist mattered.

If in eval_sets the training DMatrix comes first, it works (first figure). If I have the eval DMatrix first, the early stopping is evaluated on the training data (second data). Which is not what you usually want. Example code below.

[image: eval_sets = [(Dtrain, 'train'), (Deval, 'eval')]]
[image: eval_sets = [(Deval, 'eval'), (Dtrain, 'train')]]

```
# train test split and retain test data for final evaluation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)  

# split train set again into train and validation set
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25)

Dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)  
Deval = xgb.DMatrix(X_val, y_val)
eval_sets = [(Dtrain, 'train'), (Deval, 'eval')]
model = xgb.train(params_booster, Dtrain, 
                  verbose_eval=verbose_eval_, evals=eval_sets,        
                  early_stopping_rounds=10, evals_result=progress, 
                  num_boost_round = 250)
```